# How to change record in table with consecutive value?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table like below :

```
Application_Number  Id_Number1  Name
1                   123         John
2                   456         Alan
3                   789         Charlie
4                   111         Patrick
5                   222         Robert
```

Then i would like to update record in one of rows become like this :

```
Application_Number  Id_Number1  Name
1                   123         Alias 1
2                   456         Alias 2
3                   789         Alias 3
4                   111         Alias 4
5                   222         Alias 5
```

if i have more than one million record do i need update syntax or any another way? I'm using SQL2008

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  Application_Number  
       ,Id_Number1  
       ,'Alias'  + CAST( ROW_NUMBER() 
                         OVER (ORDER BY Application_Number) AS Varchar) AS Name
FROM Table Name
```

Comment: Hi Ali, Many thanks for your answer its succeed to be implemented

Comment: Hi Ali but after implemented then i queried it can't updated, how to combine the script above with " update" ?